# Why this Node List doesen't work correct?

Tags: c++, list

Why, although I have add 4 GameObjects, in the GameLoop the Console give only one times "GameObject Update" and "GameObject Render" out ?

And another Qustion, how I can made a Self Destroy Function for the GameObjects?

And the last Question, whats the best methode, that a GameObject can communicate with other game objects in the list?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject *nextGameObject;

    GameObject()
    {
        cout<<"GameObject Constructor!\n";
        nextGameObject = nullptr;
    }
    ~GameObject()
    {
        cout<<"GameObject Destructor\n";
        if(nextGameObject != nullptr)
        {
            delete nextGameObject;
        }
    }

    virtual void Update()
    {
        cout<<"GameObject Update!\n";
    }
    virtual void Render()
    {
        cout<<"GameObject Render!\n";
    }
};

class GameObjectManager
{
private:
    GameObject *firstGameObject;
public:
    GameObjectManager()
    {
        firstGameObject = nullptr;
    }
    ~GameObjectManager()
    {
        if(firstGameObject != nullptr)
        {
            delete firstGameObject;
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(firstGameObject != nullptr)
        {
            GameObject *helpGameObject = firstGameObject;
            while(helpGameObject != nullptr)
            {
                helpGameObject->Update();
                helpGameObject = helpGameObject->nextGameObject;
            }
        }
    }
    void Render()
    {
        if(firstGameObject != nullptr)
        {
            GameObject *helpGameObject = firstGameObject;
            while(helpGameObject != nullptr)
            {
                helpGameObject->Render();
                helpGameObject = helpGameObject->nextGameObject;
            }
        }
    }

    void Add(GameObject *newGameObject)
    {
        if(firstGameObject == nullptr)
        {
            firstGameObject = newGameObject;
        }
        else
        {
            GameObject *helpGameObject = firstGameObject;
            while(helpGameObject != nullptr)
            {
                helpGameObject = helpGameObject->nextGameObject;
            }
            helpGameObject = newGameObject;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    GameObjectManager gom;
    bool run = true;

    gom.Add(new GameObject);
    gom.Add(new GameObject);
    gom.Add(new GameObject);
    gom.Add(new GameObject);

    while(run)
    {
        cout<<"GameLoop Start\n";
        gom.Update();
        gom.Render();
        cout<<"GameLoop End\n";
        cin.get();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) might be of interest to you.

Comment: one question per question please

Comment: And a fourth question: Why didn't you work out the bugs in the `Manager` using a simpler `GameObject` class?

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible solution for a linked list, but I'll answer your question. The fault is in Add(). Here, you just modify the local variable helpGameObject. Instead you should stop at the object that has no successor and modify that objects nextGameObject.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `Add` function.

the follwing line:

```
helpGameObject = newGameObject;
```

doesn't actually change the value pointed to by `helpGameObject`, rather it changes the pointer itself.

I think the best solution is to change it to the following

```
        GameObject *helpGameObject = firstGameObject;
        while(helpGameObject->nextGameObject != nullptr)
        {
            helpGameObject = helpGameObject->nextGameObject;
        }
        helpGameObject->nextGameObject = newGameObject;
```